# what is the expression for (character spaces character) or(spaces character spaces) in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Here i am checking only for sapaces

```
if (/^\s*$/.test(txtSSAETitle.value) || /[\s]/.test(txtSSAETitle.value)){
    txtSSAETitle.focus();
    alert("AE title should not be blank.");
    return false;              
}
```

but [spacesjohnspacesHenry] or [johnspacesHenry]  this should be allowed.(No alert generate for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if input only contains spaces, [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the input and check the length of the result, I would say. Like:

```
if ( txtSSAETitle.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'').length<1 )  {  /* etc */ }
```